# Is 良識の府 a wordplay for 参院?

Tags: meaning, nuances

In a newspaper article about i stumbled on this phrase:

> 参院は、まがりなりにも「良識の府」「再考の府」と言われてきた。

The context is that a bill has been passed from the Lower House of the Diet (衆院) to the Upper House of the Diet (参院). Passing the 衆院 is the bigger hurdle, so the 参院-matters are deemed less important.

In an japanese-german online dictionary i found the same translation for 参院 and 良識の府, meaning Upper House. 
Since 良識 also means "good sense", is 良識の府 the "government of good sense", so some kind of wordplay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「良識の府」(and 「再考の府」) would be an [epithet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithet) for the House of Councillors (参議院), the upper house of the Japanese Diet. (I think "the Seat of Good Sense" may be a better translation.)  There doesn't seem to be any wordplay involved in it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia's page on 参議院](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%82%E8%AD%B0%E9%99%A2):

> 良い緊張感を保ちながら誠実な議論の積み重ねが行われる「良識の府」となることは参議院の一つの理想であるといえる
>
> It is one ideal of the House of Councilors to become a "good sense of government" where accumulation of sincere debate is held while maintaining a good tension

I don't know that I would categorize it as 'wordplay'. Just another name for that holds a more idealistic meaning. Same as 再考の府 is used to demonstrate their function（法案の再度審議）.